# CoreBluetooth two-way communication

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I am using `CBPeripheralManager`

```
- (BOOL) updateValue: (NSData *) value forCharacteristic: (CBMutableCharacteristic *) characteristic onSubscribedCentrals: (NSArray *) centrals;
```

Can be used to send data from peripherals to the central[CentralManager] .

But how can I send data from central`[CBCentralManager]` to Peripherals?
There is no method for that?

At last, how `CBPeripheralManager` receive data？

I have a question about CoreBluetooth

Here is the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1trn7LauGlrWmdIQUJkcldvZzg/edit?usp=sharing

There are two projects are Central and Peripheral

When the Peripheral connections Central. There is one in the Peripheral SendData method that can send data to the Central, in Central has a method for receiving data

- (void) peripheral: (CBPeripheral *) _peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: (CBCharacteristic *) characteristic error: (NSError *) error

The question is, how can I send data from the Central and Peripheral receives it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CoreBluetoothPeripheral in your app

https://github.com/liquidx/CoreBluetoothPeripheral
it will allow you to send and receive data.
Meanwhile you can contact for helping at skype(boygaggoo)

Comment: I have a question about CoreBluetooth

Here is the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1trn7LauGlrWmdIQUJkcldvZzg/edit?usp=sharing

There are two projects are Central and Peripheral
The question is, how can I send data from the Central and Peripheral receives it?
you gave me CoreBluetoothPeripheral . but I can't see any method useful for that.Would you check my code?thank you a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type` method from the `CBPeripheral` that your `CBCentralManager` has discovered.

Also you will have to implement the `peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` protocol method form the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`.

Here are the links for the Apple reference:

- CBPeripheral - [write value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:)
- CBPeripheralManagerDelegate - [respond to write request](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate/peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:)

Hope it helps!